# Reading metadata with Python

Tags: python, windows, metadata

For the past two days I have been scanning the Internet to try to find the solution to my problem. I have a folder of different files. They run the gambit of file types. I am trying to write a python script that will read the metadata from each file, if it exists. The intent is to eventually output the data to a file to compare with another program's metadata extraction.

I have found some examples where it worked for a very few number of the files in the directory. All the ways I have found have dealt with opening a Storage Container object. I am new to Python and am not sure what a Storage Container object is. I just know that most of my files error out when trying to use

```
pythoncom.StgOpenStorage(<File Name>, None, flags)
```

With the few that actually work, I am able to get the main metadata tags, like Title, Subject, Author, Created, etc.

Does anyone know a way other than Storage Containers to get to the metadata? Also, if there is an easier way to do this with another language, by all means, suggest it.

Thanks

Comment: "the metadata"? There's literally thousands of metadata sets and formats they can be stored in (Dublin Core, ID3, Exif, ...). What metadata set are you referring to and in what format is it stored?

Comment: "Metadata" is a very general, and vague, term. Exactly what kinds of metadata are you looking for? (If you don't know the answer, tell us what program you want to compare with.) Meanwhile, `StgOpenStorage` opens Windows Structured Storage files (and old-style OLE Compound files), and can get the metadata defined by that format.

Comment: It appear you will need to use windows API for that. A vague way is mentioned here. http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/269/285/

Comment: I'm sorry I was so vague when I asked the question. I did say some metadata tags like Title, Subject, Author, Creation Time. I couldn't give all the ones I'm looking for, because I won't ever know all of them at a given time.

Sometimes I will only need Author, Created On, Last Author, Last Saved, Revision Number.

Sometimes I will need all the ones above, as well as Page Count, Word Count, Character Count, Time Last Printed, Editing Time.

Other times I will need to get things like Email Subject, Email To, Email From, Email BCC, Email CC, Email Sent Time, Email Received Time.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the Shell com objects to retrieve any metadata
visible in Explorer:

```
import win32com.client
sh=win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Shell.Application',0)
ns = sh.NameSpace(r'm:\music\Aerosmith\Classics Live!')
colnum = 0
columns = []
while True:
    colname=ns.GetDetailsOf(None, colnum)
    if not colname:
        break
    columns.append(colname)
    colnum += 1

for item in ns.Items():
    print (item.Path)
    for colnum in range(len(columns)):
        colval=ns.GetDetailsOf(item, colnum)
        if colval:
            print('\t', columns[colnum], colval)
```

Comment: N.B __if you just want info for a specific file__ then __`item = ns.ParseName('song.mp4')`__ instead of the loop. _In fact, if you have `from pathlib import Path` then try `file = Path(r'C:\path\to\file.ext')` and use `ns = sh.NameSpace(str(file.parent))`, `item = ns.ParseName(str(file.name))`_

Answer (score 7):

I decided to write my own answer as an attempt to combine and clarify the answers above (which heavily helped me solve my problems).

I'd say there are two approaches to this problem.

**Situation 1: you know which metadata the file contains (which metadata you're interested in).**

In this case, lets say you have a list of strings, which contains the metadata you're interested in. I assume here that these tags are correct (i.e. you're not interested in the number of pixels of a .txt file).

```
metadata = ['Name', 'Size', 'Item type', 'Date modified', 'Date created']
```

Now, using the code provided by Greedo and Roger Upole I created a function which accepts the file's full path and name separately and returns a dictionary containing the metadata of interest:

```py
def get_file_metadata(path, filename, metadata):
    # Path shouldn't end with backslash, i.e. "E:\Images\Paris"
    # filename must include extension, i.e. "PID manual.pdf"
    # Returns dictionary containing all file metadata.
    sh = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Shell.Application', 0)
    ns = sh.NameSpace(path)

    # Enumeration is necessary because ns.GetDetailsOf only accepts an integer as 2nd argument
    file_metadata = dict()
    item = ns.ParseName(str(filename))
    for ind, attribute in enumerate(metadata):
        attr_value = ns.GetDetailsOf(item, ind)
        if attr_value:
            file_metadata[attribute] = attr_value

    return file_metadata

# *Note: you must know the total path to the file.*
# Example usage:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder = 'E:\Docs\BMW'
    filename = 'BMW series 1 owners manual.pdf'
    metadata = ['Name', 'Size', 'Item type', 'Date modified', 'Date created']
    print(get_file_metadata(folder, filename, metadata))
```

Results with:

```
{'Name': 'BMW series 1 owners manual.pdf', 'Size': '11.4 MB', 'Item type': 'Foxit Reader PDF Document', 'Date modified': '8/30/2020 11:10 PM', 'Date created': '8/30/2020 11:10 PM'}
```

Which is correct, as I just created the file and I use Foxit PDF reader as my main pdf reader.
So this function returns a dictionary, where the keys are the metadata tags and the values are the values of those tags for the given file.

**Situtation 2: you don't know which metadata the file contains**

This is a somewhat tougher situation, especially in terms of optimality. I analyzed the code proposed by Roger Upole, and well, basically, he attempts to read metadata of a `None` file, which results in him obtaining a list of all possible metadata tags. So I thought it might just be easier to hardcopy this list and then attempt to read every tag. That way, once you're done, you'll have a dictionary containing all tags the file actually possesses.

Simply copy what I **THINK** is every possible metadata tag and just attempt to obtain all the tags from the file.
Basically, just copy this declaration of a python list, and use the code above (replace metadata with this new list):

```
metadata = ['Name', 'Size', 'Item type', 'Date modified', 'Date created', 'Date accessed', 'Attributes', 'Offline status', 'Availability', 'Perceived type', 'Owner', 'Kind', 'Date taken', 'Contributing artists', 'Album', 'Year', 'Genre', 'Conductors', 'Tags', 'Rating', 'Authors', 'Title', 'Subject', 'Categories', 'Comments', 'Copyright', '#', 'Length', 'Bit rate', 'Protected', 'Camera model', 'Dimensions', 'Camera maker', 'Company', 'File description', 'Masters keywords', 'Masters keywords']
```

I don't think this is a great solution, but on the other hand, you can keep this list as a global variable and then use it without needing to pass it to every function call. For the sake of completness, here is the output of the previous function using this new metadata list:

```
{'Name': 'BMW series 1 owners manual.pdf', 'Size': '11.4 MB', 'Item type': 'Foxit Reader PDF Document', 'Date modified': '8/30/2020 11:10 PM', 'Date created': '8/30/2020 11:10 PM', 'Date accessed': '8/30/2020 11:10 PM', 'Attributes': 'A', 'Perceived type': 'Unspecified', 'Owner': 'KEMALS-ASPIRE-E\\kemal', 'Kind': 'Document', 'Rating': 'Unrated'}
```

As you can see, the dictionary returned now contains all the metadata that the file contains.
The reason this works is because of the *if statement*:

```
if attribute_value:
```

which means that whenever an attribute is equal to `None`, it won't be added to the returning dictionary.

I'd underline that in case of processing many files it would be better to declare the list as a global/static variable, instead of passing it to the function every time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there are two ways that Windows stores file metadata. The approach you're using is suitable for files created by COM applications; this data is included inside the file itself. However, with the introduction of NTFS5, any file can contain metadata as part of an alternate data stream. So it's possible the files that succeed are COM-app created ones, and the ones that are failing aren't.

Here's a possibly more robust way of dealing with the COM-app created files: [Get document summary information from any file](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get-document-summary-info.html).

With alternate data streams, it's possible to read them directly:

```
meta = open('myfile.ext:StreamName').read()
```

*Update:* okay, now I see none of this is relevant because you were after *document* metadata and not *file* metadata. What a difference clarity in a question can make :|

Try this: [How to retrieve author of a office file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021141/how-to-retrieve-author-of-a-office-file-in-python)

Comment: As I said, I am completely new to Python. If my file is test1.doc, what would I put in the single quotes?

Comment: Try 'ZoneInfo'. The problem is this won't help you with what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows API Code Pack** may be used with **[Python for .NET](https://pythonnet.github.io/)** to read/write file metadata.

1. Download the NuGet packages for [WindowsAPICodePack-Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Core/1.1.2) and
   [WindowsAPICodePack-Shell](http://WindowsAPICodePack-Shell)
2. Extract the *.nupkg* files with a compression utility like 7-Zip to the script's path or someplace defined in the system path variable.
3. Install Python for .NET with `pip install pythonnet`.

Example code to get and set the title of an MP4 video:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell")
from Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell import ShellFile

# create shell file object
f = ShellFile.FromFilePath(r'movie..mp4')

# read video title
print(f.Properties.System.Title.Value)

# set video title
f.Properties.System.Title.Value = 'My video'
```

Hack to check available properties:

```
dir(f.Properties.System)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem and ended up creating a package to solve my problem: [windows-metadata](https://pypi.org/project/windows-metadata/).

An aside, Roger Upole's answer was a good starting point, however it doesn't capture all the attributes a file can have (the break if not colname ends the loop too soon, since Windows skips some column numbers, for whatever reason. So Roger's answer gives the first 30 or so attributes, when there are actually nearly 320).

Now, to answer the question using this package:

```
from windows_metadata import WindowsAttributes

attr = WindowsAttributes(<File Name>)  # this will load all the filled attributes a file has
title = attr["Title"] # dict-like access
title = attr.title # attribute like access -> these two will return the same value
subject = attr.subject
author = attr.author
...
```

And so on for any available attributes a file has.

Answer (score 0):

Roger Upole's answer helped immensely. However, I also needed to read the "last saved by" detail in an ".xls" file.

XLS file attributes can be read with `win32com`. The `Workbook` object has a `BuiltinDocumentProperties`.
https://gist.github.com/justengel/87bac3355b1a925288c59500d2ce6ef5

```
import os
import win32com.client  # Requires "pip install pywin32"


__all__ = ['get_xl_properties', 'get_file_details']


# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.builtindocumentproperties?view=vsto-2017
BUILTIN_XLS_ATTRS = ['Title', 'Subject', 'Author', 'Keywords', 'Comments', 'Template', 'Last Author', 'Revision Number',
                     'Application Name', 'Last Print Date', 'Creation Date', 'Last Save Time', 'Total Editing Time',
                     'Number of Pages', 'Number of Words', 'Number of Characters', 'Security', 'Category', 'Format',
                     'Manager', 'Company', 'Number of Btyes', 'Number of Lines', 'Number of Paragraphs',
                     'Number of Slides', 'Number of Notes', 'Number of Hidden Slides', 'Number of Multimedia Clips',
                     'Hyperlink Base', 'Number of Characters (with spaces)']


def get_xl_properties(filename, xl=None):
    """Return the known XLS file attributes for the given .xls filename."""
    quit = False
    if xl is None:
        xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
        quit = True

    # Open the workbook
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(filename)

    # Save the attributes in a dictionary
    attrs = {}
    for attrname in BUILTIN_XLS_ATTRS:
        try:
            val = wb.BuiltinDocumentProperties(attrname).Value
            if val:
                attrs[attrname] = val
        except:
            pass

    # Quit the excel application
    if quit:
        try:
            xl.Quit()
            del xl
        except:
            pass

    return attrs


def get_file_details(directory, filenames=None):
    """Collect the a file or list of files attributes.
    Args:
        directory (str): Directory or filename to get attributes for
        filenames (str/list/tuple): If the given directory is a directory then a filename or list of files must be given
    Returns:
         file_attrs (dict): Dictionary of {filename: {attribute_name: value}} or dictionary of {attribute_name: value}
            if a single file is given.
    """
    if os.path.isfile(directory):
        directory, filenames = os.path.dirname(directory), [os.path.basename(directory)]
    elif filenames is None:
        filenames = os.listdir(directory)
    elif not isinstance(filenames, (list, tuple)):
        filenames = [filenames]

    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        raise ValueError('The given directory does not exist!')

    # Open the com object
    sh = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Shell.Application', 0)  # Generates local compiled with make.py
    ns = sh.NameSpace(os.path.abspath(directory))

    # Get the directory file attribute column names
    cols = {}
    for i in range(512):  # 308 seemed to be max for excel file
        attrname = ns.GetDetailsOf(None, i)
        if attrname:
            cols[i] = attrname

    # Get the information for the files.
    files = {}
    for file in filenames:
        item = ns.ParseName(os.path.basename(file))
        files[os.path.abspath(item.Path)] = attrs = {}  # Store attributes in dictionary

        # Save attributes
        for i, attrname in cols.items():
            attrs[attrname] = ns.GetDetailsOf(item, i)

        # For xls file save special properties
        if os.path.splitext(file)[-1] == '.xls':
            xls_attrs = get_xl_properties(item.Path)
            attrs.update(xls_attrs)

    # Clean up the com object
    try:
        del sh
    except:
        pass

    if len(files) == 1:
        return files[list(files.keys())[0]]
    return files


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse

    P = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Read and print file details.")
    P.add_argument('filename', type=str, help='Filename to read and print the details for.')
    P.add_argument('-v', '--show-empty', action='store_true', help='If given print keys with empty values.')
    ARGS = P.parse_args()

    # Argparse Variables
    FILENAME = ARGS.filename
    SHOW_EMPTY = ARGS.show_empty
    DETAILS = get_file_details(FILENAME)

    print(os.path.abspath(FILENAME))
    for k, v in DETAILS.items():
        if v or SHOW_EMPTY:
            print('\t', k, '=', v)
```

Comment: This method did not work for me.  It was unable to find the "Last Author" tag, despite finding many other tags.  Perhaps it does not work on xlsx, or the python library has a bug.  This method worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69690437/86969 (just manually read from the xml data).

Comment: Try just calling the ``get_xls_properties`` function. It might be an excel version thing. I have the condition to only use that function if it is a .xls file, but it should work for all excel files. The main problem is that function takes a long time, because it actually opens Excel to read the data.

Comment: Oh, boy...you are right.  It works fine on xlsx.