# How can I retrieve a file's details in Windows using the Standard Library for Python 2

Tags: python, file, properties, ctypes

I need to read the details for a file in Windows so that I can interrogate the file's 'File version' as displayed in the Details tab of the File Properties window.

[image: File Properties Dialog]

I haven't found anything in the standard library that makes this very easy to accomplish but figured if I could find the right windows function, I could probably accomplish it using ctypes.

Does anyone have any exemplary code or can they point me to a Windows function that would let me read this info. I took a look a [GetFileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944(v=vs.85).aspx) already, but that wasn't quite right as far as I could tell.

Comment: does this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521525/reading-metadata-with-python help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading metadata with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521525/reading-metadata-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the win32 api [Version Information functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms646981) from [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html). The api is a little fiddly to use, but I also want this so have thrown together [a quick script](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gz/+junk/version_info/view/head:/version_info.py) as an example.

```
usage: version_info.py [-h] [--lang LANG] [--codepage CODEPAGE] path
```

Can also use as a module, see the VersionInfo class. Checked with Python 2.7 and 3.6 against a few files.

Answer (score 0):

```
import array
from ctypes import *

def get_file_info(filename, info):
    """
    Extract information from a file.
    """
    # Get size needed for buffer (0 if no info)
    size = windll.version.GetFileVersionInfoSizeA(filename, None)

    # If no info in file -> empty string
    if not size:
        return ''

    # Create buffer
    res = create_string_buffer(size)
    # Load file informations into buffer res
    windll.version.GetFileVersionInfoA(filename, None, size, res)
    r = c_uint()
    l = c_uint()
    # Look for codepages
    windll.version.VerQueryValueA(res, '\\VarFileInfo\\Translation',
                              byref(r), byref(l))

    # If no codepage -> empty string
    if not l.value:
        return ''
    # Take the first codepage (what else ?)
    codepages = array.array('H', string_at(r.value, l.value))
    codepage = tuple(codepages[:2].tolist())

    # Extract information
    windll.version.VerQueryValueA(res, ('\\StringFileInfo\\%04x%04x\\'
    + info) % codepage, byref(r), byref(l))

    return string_at(r.value, l.value)
```