# Python: save pickle adding details of the generating script

Tags: python, windows, numpy, pickle, file-properties

I want to be able to retrieve the location of the script that created a certain `pickle` file. This happens especially if I work on a project, then stop, and after some time I need to come back.

In these cases, wouldn't it be easier if we could retrieve the script path by simply right-clicking on the `pickle` file we are working with, and read the path from the *Properties->Details* tab of the file?

- If you create the following `numpy` array, which is meant to represent *any* object, and save it as a `pickle`, is there a way to add to the file details the path of the generating script?

  ```
  #Generating script: C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\hopethisworks.py
  import numpy
  import pickle

  a=numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

  with open('myarray.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
      pickle.dump(a, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  ```

Comment: This is not special to `numpy` or `pickle`.  It's about writing to the Window's properties from Python.

Comment: You may need a 3rd party package like `win32ext` (I'm have trouble finding documentation on that without downloading the whole thing).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521525/reading-metadata-with-python - seems to have the best answer on accessing the windows file metadata.