# Python get meta data for hidden files on windows

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I have been using the replies from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521525/reading-metadata-with-python) to read out the metadata of files on windows.
However i noticed that it would just ignore hidden files.

How can one also include hidden files in this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine python's [os library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) with Windows' [Shell.Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-application) object, as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12541871/403671), something like this:

```
import os
import win32com.client

sh = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Shell.Application', 0)
path = r'c:\mypath\myfolder'
ns = sh.NameSpace(path)

colnum = 0
columns = []
while True:
    colname=ns.GetDetailsOf(None, colnum)
    if not colname:
        break
    columns.append(colname)
    colnum += 1

for name in os.listdir(path): # list all files
    print(path + '\\' + name)
    item = ns.ParseName(name)
    for colnum in range(len(columns)):
        colval=ns.GetDetailsOf(item, colnum)
        if colval:
            print('\t', columns[colnum], colval)
```

hidden files will display (H attribute is for Hidden)

```
...
Attributes HA
...
```

Comment: I probably should have thought of that myself... instead i went digging around here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-enumobjects.

Thanks so much!

Comment: @J.N. - Shell.Application is a wrapper over these native API and interfaces.