# Python: How to Modify metadata of Microsoft Office files?

Tags: python-2.7, file, python-3.x, metadata

How can I modify Microsoft Office Document's Metadata? I found number of result for the Jpg, PNG and PDF file. Any one can suggest Libraries for Office files Metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For newer formats they are often just zipped xml, so you can use standard libs to unzip and parse the xml. Some code to grab the document creator was previously [posted as an answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7021492/1341437).

```
import zipfile, lxml.etree

# open zipfile
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('my_doc.docx')
# use lxml to parse the xml file we are interested in
doc = lxml.etree.fromstring(zf.read('docProps/core.xml'))
# retrieve creator
ns={'dc': 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'}
creator = doc.xpath('//dc:creator', namespaces=ns)[0].text
```

For older formats you might want to look at the [hachoir-metadata library](https://pypi.org/project/hachoir-metadata/)