# How to get .xlsx detail (such Author, created, modified) that encrypted with password?

Tags: python, excel, password-protection, zip

I want to get detail of .xlsx file that encrypted with password (Author, Created, Modified) . I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021141/how-to-retrieve-author-of-a-office-file-in-python/7021492#7021492) that can get what I need. But with encryped with password file, error was occur.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-32-254f87dddcce>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Python/Code/testFindAuthor.py', wdir='D:/Python/Code')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Python/Code/testFindAuthor.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(get_creator(filePath))

  File "D:/Python/Code/testFindAuthor.py", line 18, in get_creator
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(pathFile)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1108, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1175, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Any idea how to get this information ?
Thank you and sorry for my language.

[This is image about set password to .xlsx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQuFq.png)