# How to find out the original author of a word document using python?

Tags: python

I have a word document, food worksheet, and I am trying to find the author(s) of the word document but I don't know how to find that out. Is there a way to find out the author of the word document using python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021141/how-to-retrieve-the-author-of-an-office-file-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Python-Docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/coreprops.html)

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document("path/to/word/file.docx")
prop = doc.core_properties
print(prop.author)
```

Comment: I have a problem where I cant import `docx` so this code doesn't work for me

Comment: have you installed docx?

Comment: I mean the python module with 'pip install python-docx'. If this doesn't work, then this is another problem on its own.

Comment: Ive installed it with no problems but when I use `import docx` it says `no module named docx`

Comment: It seems that you haven't installed it correctly, else you would be able to import it. Solve this and the above code will work. I think it's the easiest way to do what you want.